# I switched to linux Mint and my printer stopped working

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, cups, printer, hp

I have a Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet Professional M1132 MFP, a couple of weeks ago I switched to Linux Mint, and now my printer won't work.

When I plug the printer in it gets recognized and I can queue jobs just fine, it goes to rendering, but it just doesn't print, it brings up a generic error message and the job is just stuck there.
I tried the troubleshooting that Linux Mint offers, and this is the result:

```
    Page 1 (<troubleshoot.SchedulerNotRunning.SchedulerNotRunning object at 0x7f78669da110>):
{'cups_connection_failure': False}
Page 2 (<troubleshoot.CheckLocalServerPublishing.CheckLocalServerPublishing object at 0x7f78669da410>):
{'local_server_exporting_printers': False}
Page 3 (<troubleshoot.ChoosePrinter.ChoosePrinter object at 0x7f78669d9a50>):
{'cups_dest': <cups.Dest HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP (default)>,
 'cups_instance': None,
 'cups_queue': 'HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP',
 'cups_queue_listed': True}
Page 4 (<troubleshoot.CheckPrinterSanity.CheckPrinterSanity object at 0x7f78669dace0>):
{'cups_device_uri_scheme': 'hp',
 'cups_printer_dict': {'device-uri': 'hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000QH411MTPR1a',
                       'printer-info': 'Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet '
                                       'Professional M1132 MFP',
                       'printer-is-shared': True,
                       'printer-location': 'Transistor',
                       'printer-make-and-model': 'HP LaserJet Professional '
                                                 'm1132 MFP, hpcups 3.21.12, '
                                                 'requires proprietary plugin',
                       'printer-state': 3,
                       'printer-state-message': 'ready to print',
                       'printer-state-reasons': ['none'],
                       'printer-type': 167948,
                       'printer-uri-supported': 'ipp://localhost/printers/HP-LaserJet-Professional-M1132-MFP'},
 'cups_printer_remote': False,
 'hplip_output': (['',
                   '\x1b[01mHP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. '
                   '3.21.12)\x1b[0m',
                   '\x1b[01mDevice Information Utility ver. 5.2\x1b[0m',
                   '',
                   'Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP',
                   'This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.',
                   'This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute '
                   'it',
                   'under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more '
                   'details.',
                   '',
                   '',
                   '\x1b[01mHP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. '
                   '3.21.12)\x1b[0m',
                   '\x1b[01mSystem Tray Status Service ver. 2.0\x1b[0m',
                   '',
                   'Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP',
                   'This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.',
                   'This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute '
                   'it',
                   'under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more '
                   'details.',
                   '',
                   '',
                   '\x1b[01mhp:/usb
```

This is just part of it, I had to cut it because of the character limit, you can find it in full here: https://pastebin.com/u7bK0Sab.

I tried looking if my driver is updated and I found out that it should be: I ran the command `dpkg -l hplip` and this was the output

```
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version         Architecture Description
+++-==============-===============-============-============================================
ii  hplip          3.21.12+dfsg0-1 amd64        HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
```

Let me know what I should do or if I should give more information.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you print from another device, in order to verify there is no issue with the printer itself? In the output you linked, there is a reference to an `error-state 103` being reported from your printer.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and successfully printed from another device (a Mac) with no issues, and before I switched from Windows 10 it printed normally.